# Could someone explain this for me - for (i = 0; i=10; i++)

Tags: php

I know this below statement works

```
for ($i= 0; $i=<10; $i++)
```

will output till 0 to 10
but when I write this code

```
for ($i=0; $i=10; $i++)
```

it print 10 for unlimited times... why  why it not print 0 to 10...
what error I have done to get the result 0 to 10 for it....

Comment: 2nd block in a `for` loop is meant for a **condition**

Comment: In for loop, first 2 condition will be evaluated first time but in your case, you are reassigning the value 10 to i that's why end of the for loop it checks the condition agian, and i will be reassigned to 10 again and again. basically 2nd expression always be condition checking rather assigning.

Comment: i=10 is a assignment statement ,not a condition

Comment: @PranavCBalan  .... but how can it will be in php == not working

Comment: *"I know this below statement works `for ($i= 0; $i=<10; $i++)`"* No it doesn't because there's no such operator as `=<`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middle term in a `for` loop is the condition that says whether the loop should continue running.  `i=10` assigns 10 to `i`, and it also evaluates to the number 10, which is not zero, so it's considered true.  Since the loop's condition is always true, it never stops running.

Comment: so how can I achieve the result .. ==10 is not working but <=10 will shown till 10 ...  no any other method ?

Comment: `i==10` is false, because `i` was set to zero, so the loop doesn't run at all.  What are you trying to accomplish?  You already know how to write the condition so the loop goes from 0 to 10.

Comment: @Wyzard for($i=1; $i==10; $i++) no output ... i am very very new in php so i want to clear and learn max ways to get anything .

Comment: You don't get output from that because the loop doesn't run, because its condition is false.  What are you trying to make the loop do?  It sounds like you want it go from 0 to 10, but you already know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

" = " sign is an assignment operator and can't be used as conditional where as >= , == , <= such operators are conditional, so while checking for a condition you should not use " = "

please write like this below

```
for($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
echo $i;
}
```

Comment: agree but when I use == , blank data/output shown $i;

for($i=0; $i==10; $i++)

{

echo"$i";
echo"<br>";

 
}

Answer (score 0):

because i=10 always be true i==10 will be good

Comment: well when I set i==10; blank data shown means no output no result

Comment: you can set i to 10 in the first statement. But then it will be print 10 and ends

Comment: i want to start from 0 .. what can other possibilities .

Answer (score 0):

The second statement in the for loop is the condition. When its not true it will leave the loop. i=10 is not a comparator. i will be set to 10 every round that loop goes and because it "works" its resulting in true. i == 10 would be a comparator but i would never be 10 in its first round.

Comment: for($i=0; $i==10; $i++) ...blank data shown means no output no result

Comment: because $i is not 10 a single time. you defined it in your first statement to be 0

Answer (score 0):

if $i< or =10 Will perform,if $i> 10 will break,each time $i will +1 you can set the $i begin to value or set the maximum to achieve the result that you want.